# Click event restart

Tags: c#

I'm using c# windows form in Visual studio 2017 version

I've made a high low game for practice and it works perfect but what I'm trying to accomplish is once someone hits 10 guesses it starts the application over again.

This was my last resort coming here and asking but i have no one else to turn to. I've tried all kinds of things to make it work when hitting 10 guesses to restart the app but nothing works and i get errors.

here's the start button and the guess button

variables I'm using

```
    static int intRandomNumber;
    static int intNumGuesses;
    static int intBestLowScore;
    static int intGuessedNum;
    static int difference = 0;
```

Start Button

```
        {
        //Random Numbers//

        Random rnRandomNumber = new Random();
        intRandomNumber = rnRandomNumber.Next(0, 1000);
        lblRandomNumber.Text = intRandomNumber.ToString();
        txtGuess.Enabled = true;
        btnGuess.Enabled = true;
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        lblAnswer.Text = "".ToString();
        intBestLowScore = intNumGuesses;
        intNumGuesses = 0;
        lblNumGuesses.Text = "0";
        lblBestScore.Text = intBestLowScore.ToString();
        lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.White;
        txtGuess.Focus();
        SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(High_Low_Game.Properties.Resources.Cheering);
        audio.Stop();
    }
```

Guess Button

```
{
        intNumGuesses++;
        lblNumGuesses.Text = intNumGuesses.ToString();

        try
        {
            intGuessedNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);


            if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum < difference)
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "To High";
                lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.White;
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                txtGuess.Focus();
            }
            else if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum > difference)
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "To Low";
                lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.White;
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                txtGuess.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "You Guessed it.";
                lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.Green;
                btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                txtGuess.Enabled = false;
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                btnStart.Enabled = true;
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(High_Low_Game.Properties.Resources.Cheering);
                audio.Play();

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input your Guess again and Integers Only.  Retry.");
            txtGuess.Focus();
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `if` statement

Guess Button:

```
private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            intNumGuesses++;
            lblNumGuesses.Text = intNumGuesses.ToString();
//This is what you're looking for-v
            if(intNumGuesses==10)
            {
                btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                txtGuess.Enabled = false;
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                btnStart.Enabled = true;
                intNumGuesses=0;
            }
//This is what you're looking for-^
            try
            {
                intGuessedNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);


                if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum < difference)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = "To High";
                    lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.White;
                    txtGuess.Text = "";
                    txtGuess.Focus();
                }
                else if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum > difference)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = "To Low";
                    lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.White;
                    txtGuess.Text = "";
                    txtGuess.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = "You Guessed it.";
                    lblAnswer.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                    txtGuess.Enabled = false;
                    txtGuess.Text = "";
                    btnStart.Enabled = true;

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input your Guess again and Integers Only.  Retry.");
                txtGuess.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'guess-button' handler do the following:

```
{
    intNumGuesses++;
    lblNumGuesses.Text = intNumGuesses.ToString();
    bool guessed = false;
    try
    {
        intGuessedNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);


        if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum < difference)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (intRandomNumber - intGuessedNum > difference)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
           ...
           guessed = true;
        }
        if ((intNumGuesses == 10}&&(!guessed))
        {
           // Show Message "max. nr. of guesses reached'
           // call method to clear values from textBoxes & enable Start-button
        }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input your Guess again and Integers Only.  Retry.");
        txtGuess.Focus();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
{
  intNumGuesses++;
  if(intNumGuesses >= 10)
  {
    StartButton(); // pseudo call, replace with whatever the name and parameters of your method really are
    return;
  }
  lblNumGuesses.Text = intNumGuesses.ToString();
  // ...
}
```

I would recommend to write an `Init()`method, that you call either from your `StartButton()` method or from your `GuessButton()` method when necessary